# Rewrite cookies for ISA: add Secure

Tags: reverse-proxy, rewrite, isa-server, cookies

We've developed a web application. One of our customers decided to run it over HTTP internally and use an ISA server to function as a reverse proxy. The access to the ISA server from the outside world is HTTPS. I want to modify all the cookies that are served from the web-application to include "; Secure". Is that possible, and how do we configure that?